# C list table from book K & R

Tags: c

Section 6.6 of K&R discusses a hash table using a linked list.

In short, a hash table is an array of pointers.  The pointers point to a linked list.  The linked list is a struct that looks like:

```
struct nlist {             /* table entry: */
    struct nlist *next;    /* next entry in chain */
    char *name;            /* defined name */
    char *defn;            /* replacement text */
};
```

The name is hashed, and this hash determines the index in the table.  The chapter then shows code to add a name/defn pair to the table:

```
struct nlist *install(char *name, char *defn) {
    struct nlist *np;
    unsigned hashval;
    if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL) { /* not found */
        np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->name = strdup(name)) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        hashval = hash(name);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    } else /* already there */
        free((void *) np->defn); /*free previous defn */
    if ((np->defn = strdup(defn)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return np;
}
```

Everything makes sense except for the following 2 lines:

```
np->next = hashtab[hashval];
hashtab[hashval] = np;
```

My question is why don't they assign it to `next` directly rather than insert it? Namely,

```
hashtab[hashval]->next = np; 
np->next = NULL;
```

What's the benefit to doing the insert trick?

Comment: To find the end of the list, you have to traverse the `next` pointers until you find the last node.

Comment: `hashtab[hashval]` is the **head pointer** of the hashval-th linked list, so the code like `hashtab[hashval]->next = np` will **lose the head pointer**, unless you do some **iterations** before you code it.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general to/from a pointer in C! And use a book which covers at least C99 - better standard C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chained hashes, you usually add new elements on the front, that's why np is always the head of the list in the hashtable. It is sort of the use of cache locality, that is, the one accessed most recently is likely to be accessed again.

Also, your change wont work because it simply add np to the next element of the hash list, but all the elements after than will be lost.

Comment: Maybe this is a reason.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is locality.

In the code, a new node inserted at the first of list in hash array list. Your suggestion when hashtab[hashval] is null(at the first) cause segmentation fault, unless you check this case in an if statement. The code adds  at the first without worried about that case.